# Remove empty json field in Component Expoter

Tags: json, adobe, aem, aem-6, sling-models

How to exclude Json tab field when it has no value being authored in component dialog field (Sling model)?

dialog

- a (authored value) tab
- b (not authored) tab

json response with model.json of experience fragment

```
"Component" : {
   "a":{
         "field":"authored value"

       },
   "b": {
         "field": null
        }
}
```

I am expecting to be removed from json response if it is not authored.

```
"Component" : {
   "a":{
         "field":"authored value"
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all Jackson Annotations (`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`) to modify JSON output. In your case:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public String getA() {....}
```